# Calculate new width & height of image keeping ratio constant & should have desired number of pixels

Tags: python, algorithm, image

I have to resize images in such a way that :-

1.) ratio should be constant (but small variations are acceptable)

2.) resultant image should have total number of pixels in given range

My pseudo algorithm is as follows:-
(Total Pixels should be between 28000 & 30000 demonstrated in algorithm)

```
ratio=width/height
for i in range(width):
    for j in range(height):
        if (i!=0)|(j!=0):
            no_of_pixels=i*j
            if (no_of_pixels>=28000)*(no_of_pixels<=30000):
                new_ratio=i/j
                if abs(new_ratio-ratio)<=0.006:
                    new_width=i
                    new_height=j
```

My pseudo algorithm works properly but issue is that it is clearly not efficient. Is there any better way to speed it up?

Comment: Is the problem only to find a suitable scaling factor? It's not completely clear to me what constraints you have. How about `scaling_factor = math.sqrt(((pixels_lower_bound + pixels_upper_bound) / 2) / (width * height))`? Then `new_width = round(scaling_factor * width); new_height = round(scaling_factor * height)`.

Comment: @Stef The restriction is the total number of pixels in the image, so it should be between 28-30 kilopixels.

Comment: @Selcuk I was requiring clarification from the asker; Since your answer is basically identical to the suggestion in my comment, I assume you and I have the same limited understanding of the question the way it is currently phrased.

Comment: @Stef There are two constraints. 1st is total number of pixels must be between 28000 & 30000. 2nd is that its ratio(width/height) should be similar to the original image (little bit variation are acceptable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find the existing area and calculate how much you should reduce (or enlarge) it:

```
import math

area = width * height
factor = math.sqrt(30000.0 / float(area))
new_width = int(width * factor)
new_height = int(height * factor)
```